# Which table moodle session time out stored to?

Tags: php, moodle

I know the default session time out in `moodle` is 2 hours . For knowing the session time out:

```
Site Administration > Server > Session handling> Timeout
```

I need to know in which table in `moodle` the time out getting stored?

**Moodle version: 2.9.1**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All Moodle site-wide configuration is stored in one of two tables.

If the name of the configuration option is displayed as 'pluginname | settingname' (in small letters under the human-readable name), then it is stored in [mdl_]config_plugins, in a record with "plugin = [pluginname]" and "name = [settingname]".

If the name of the configuration option is displayed as 'setting name' (without the '|' symbol), then it is stored in [mdl_]config, in a record with "name = [settingname]".

So, in this case, it is stored in [mdl_]config, with "name = 'sessiontimeout'".

You should normally use the "get_config($pluginname, [$settingname])" function to retrieve settings and the "set_config($settingname, $value, [$pluginname])" function to set settings. If you are wanting to change a setting in the database, you will need to make sure you [purge all the caches](https://docs.moodle.org/en/Purge_all_cache) when you do so, as all these settings are cached (set_config, if used, automatically updates the cache for you).

Comment: @buddy you are fantastic, thank you very much!! I got it!! `SELECT * FROM `mdl_config` WHERE `name` LIKE '%sessiontimeout%'  `